# Probabilty to choose x times (or more) one bin with a specific probabilty

Tags: probability

I've two bins, one bin (bin A) has a probability y to be taken, the other (bin B) 1-y. I pick N=1000 times one of the two bins (using their respective probabilities). What is the probabilty to choose X time or more the bin A ?

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: You simply sum the binomial probabilities from X to and including N.